How to disable local dashboard netdata when deployed using helm
I deployed Netdata using the default helm package on a Kubernetes cluster, but I'm having trouble disabling the local dashboard deployed on node:19999.
Following the documentation:
https://learn.netdata.cloud/docs/netdata-agent/securing-netdata-agents/#disable-the-local-dashboard
It should be as simple as setting the web mode to none. So under the netdata config section in the helm yaml I added the config, but no luck, after doing that the containers simply don't start.
child:
  netdata:
      data: |
        [db]
          mode = ram
        [health]
          enabled = no
        [ml]
          enabled = no
        [web]
          mode = none

I also attempted the same under the parent, no luck. Anyone here know how to disable the local dashboard?
